# Bash: no output of while loop and any better solution?

Tags: bash, error-handling

I am new to bash scripting and the part of my script below doesn't give me any output.

```
check=""
while [ "$check"=="" ]
do
    read -p "Signature Correct?(Yes/No): " check

if [ "$check" != "Y" || "$check" != "y" || "$check" != "Yes" || "$check" != "yes" || "$check" != "N" || "$check" != "n" || "$check" != "No" || "$check" != "no" ];
then
    check=""
elif ["$check" == "Y" || "$check" == "y" || "$check" == "Yes" || "$check" == "yes" ];
then
    echo "Signature Accepted!"
elif [ "$check" != "N" || "$check" != "n" || "$check" != "No" || "$check" != "no" ];
then
    check=""
fi
done
```

I don't get any error message. Any help with this? If you have a smarter or shorter solution, I would be grateful to benefit from the knowledge.

Thank you!

Comment: The `==` operator must be surrounded by spaces, always. Please consider using http://shellcheck.net to check the syntax of your scripts. A simple `case $check in ([Yy]|[Yy]es) ...` test would be easier to read than your long `||` lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    read -p 'Is signature correct? y/[n]: '

    [[ $REPLY == [Yy]* ]] && break

    echo 'Ok, asking again...'
done

echo 'Signature accepted'
```

This implements an infinite loop that the user breaks out of by entering a string beginning with either `y` or `Y` but that defaults to interpret the input as "no".

If you need to check for `Y`, `y`, `Yes` and `yes` (i.e., to treat  strings like `yup` as "no"), then use

```
case $REPLY in ([Yy]|[Yy]es) break; esac
```

instead of the `[[ ... ]]` test and `break`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's two different ways. The first one use regular expressions to match yes/no, the other uses the `select` builtin instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Version 1"

check=
while [[ -z $check ]]; do
    read -r -p "Signature Correct? (Yes/No): " check
    if [[ $check =~ ^[Nn]o?$ ]]; then
        echo "Try again"
        check=
    elif [[ $check =~ ^[Yy](es)?$ ]]; then
        echo "Signature accepted"
        break;
    else
        echo "Invalid input."
        check=
    fi
done

echo "Version 2"

PS3="Signature Correct? (1 for Yes/ 2 for No): "
select opt in Yes No; do
    case $opt in
        Yes)
            echo "Signature accepted"
            break;;
        No)
            echo "Try again.";;
        *)
            echo "Invalid input."
    esac;
done
```